# Fading one image out while another in using CSS transitions on opacity isn't smooth?

Tags: css, css-transitions, opacity

I placed two images on top of one another (one in black and white and the other in color) and created a CSS transition wherein the opacity of one image decreases while the other increases. The result is a [color on hover effect](http://jsfiddle.net/orvn/qvcRf/3/).

I'm having an issue though: at some point during the transition you can see through the image a little, indicating that the transition of opacity isn't linear even though the "transition-timing-function" property is set to linear.

If there was some kind of quadratic easing involved I'd understand why this is happening, but there shouldn't be?

(the reason I'm approaching this with pure CSS is because I haven't fully tackled JQuery yet)

Any ideas on how I can better implement this functionality?

My CSS is below, or [visit this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orvn/qvcRf/3/).

```
#container { width: 210px; height: 150px; display:block; border: 4px solid #ccc; position:relative; overflow:hidden; margin: 10px 0 0 10px;}

.image { width: 210px; height: 150px; display:block; position:absolute; left: 0px; top:0px; }

#dbw { 
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    background: url("http://oi42.tinypic.com/x0y2ky.jpg"); 
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

#dco { 
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    background: url("http://oi40.tinypic.com/28gwcrb.jpg"); 
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}

#container:hover #dbw { 
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
    opacity: 0; 
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}

#container:hover #dco { 
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
    opacity: 1; 
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that the transition isn't linear, it's simply that if you put two non-opaque images on top of each other, the background is always partly visible.

For example, where the transitions meat in the middle, both images are 50% opaque. The bottom image covers 50% of the background, and the top image covers 50% of the remaining 50% of the background, leaving 25% of the background shining though.

Just leave the bottom image opaque, and let the top image take over in the transition:

http://jsfiddle.net/qvcRf/4/

I.e. remove the opacity transition on the bottom image:

```
#container:hover #dbw { 
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1); 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```